# SQL output adjustment

Tags: sql, oracle

I have below table:

```
student  marks  subject
-------  -----  -------
AAA         67  ENG
AAA         78  MAT
CCC         88  SCI
```

I want it to convert as below:

```
student  eng  mat  sci
-------  ---  ---  ---
AAA       67   78     
CCC                 88
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with dat as (
   select 'AAA' stud, 67 mk, 'ENG' subj from dual union all 
   select 'AAA' stud, 78 mk, 'MAT' subj from dual union all
   select 'CCC' stud, 88 mk, 'SCI' subj from dual )
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT stud, mk, subj from dat)
PIVOT (max(mk) for  (subj) in ('ENG' as eng, 'MAT' as mat, 'SCI' as sci)) 

STUD ENG MAT SCI
AAA  67  78 
CCC          88
```